# I am trying to get a random item from an array that is in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random, printing

I am at the beginning stages of creating what I think should essentially be an easy little program.  However, I am very new to java so it is proving to be more difficult than expected.  This is what I have that will compile except for the printing part at the end. Firstly, I don't understand why not? secondly, I need to create a random generator to randomly pick an item from one of the arrays within the arrayList. I have been trying so many things but just can't get it to work. I think I am confused as to where to even put the code.  HELP!

```
import java.util.*;

public class RestaurantSelector1 {

    //public static class Tribeca4star{
    final static String[] italian = {"Pepolino Restaurant", "Locanda Verde", "Scalini Fedeli", "Gran Morsi", "Ecco", "Tutto il Giorno", "The Odeon", "Mamo Restaurant", "Petrarca Cucina E Vino", "Osteria Morini"};
    final static String[] japanese = {"Shigure", "Sushi Azabu", "Ichimura", "Brushstroke", "Takahachi Tribeca Restaurant", "Ninja New York", "DOMODOMO", "Sushi of Gari", "Hirohisa", "Blue Ribbon"};
    final static String[] french = {"Bouley", "Batard", "Racines", "The Odeon", "MAMO Restaurant", "La Sirene", "Le Coucou", "Balthazar", "Taureau", "L'Appart"};
    final static String[] american = {"American Cut Steakhouse", "Marc Forgione", "The Bennett", "Little Park", "The Odeon", "Yves", "Tribeca Grill", "Atera", "Batard", "Brandy Library"};
    final static String[] chinese = {"Mr. Chow", "Macao", "Khe-Yo"};
    final static String[] spanish = {"Tablao", "Sazon", "Despana", "Estancia 460", "Westside Coffee Shop", "Anejo Tribeca", "Terra Wine Bar", "Darlene", "Sophia's Cuban Cuisine", "Amada"};
    final static String[] cafe = { "Arcade Bakery", "Galerie de Cafe", "The Wooly Daily", "Cafe Belle", "Baked", "Laughing Man Coffee and Tea","La Colombe Coffee", "Kuro-Obi at Canal Street Market", "Blue Spoon Coffee", "Everyman Espresso"};
    final static String[] thai = {"khe-yo", "Empire", "Macao"};
    final static String[] indian = {"Tamarind"};
    final static String[] viatnamese = {"Khe-Yo", "Macao"};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String[]> cuisine = new ArrayList<>();

        cuisine.add(italian);
        cuisine.add(japanese);
        cuisine.add(french);
        cuisine.add(american);
        cuisine.add(chinese);
        cuisine.add(spanish);
        cuisine.add(cafe);
        cuisine.add(thai);
        cuisine.add(indian);
        cuisine.add(viatnamese);

        System.out.println(cuisine[0,1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please separate the syntax error question from "randomly pick an item" question.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random index by creating a new Random() instance, and getting a random int from `nextInt`, from `[0,cuisine.size())` for the random language and `[0,cuisine.get(rnd).length)` for the word within that language

```
Random rand = new Random();                         //RN Generator
int rnd     = rand.nextInt(cuisine.size());         //random lang index
int rndWord = rand.nextInt(cuisine.get(rnd).length) //random word index
```

You can then use the random index with `.get(rnd)` to access the String[] you want, and get the random entry in that array with `[rndWord]`.

```
System.out.print( cuisine.get(rnd)[rndWord] );      //print out random word
```

Comment: But cuisine should be .size right? When I do that it says size doesnt have public access?

Comment: make sure you are doing .size() and not .size @danaCarlin

Comment: @danaCarlin see my edits to get the random word from all sets

Answer (score 0):

try `System.out.println(cuisine.get(0)[1])`

You want to use `ArrayList.get(int index)` in order to retrieve your `String[]` object, and then you can point to a String within that array

Comment: Hi! How would I get a random restaurant from say italian?  Everything compiles except the final line, I don't know how to get a specific type of cuisine then a random restaurant within that.

Comment: I want you to be able to think about it without just giving the answer away, or you won't learn. 

What you want to do is think of it as multiple steps. 
You need a random Integer. 
You need your String[] of Italian food, 
the String[] of Italian food lives inside your ArrayList. 

Get that String[] from the ArrayList, and get a random index from that String[]. 
It may be easier for you if it is not all in one line. Assign each variable and work like that. Message back if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

To get a random restaurant from a random cuisine, you can do the following:

```
final Random random = new Random();
final String[] randomCuisine = cuisine.get(random.nextInt(cuisine.size()));
final String randomRestaurant = randomCuisine[random.nextInt(randomCuisine.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get a random `String[]` of your list, and then get a random entry out of the `String[]`. You can get that by using the `java.util.Random` class:

```
public static String getRandom(List<String[]> list) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int listAccess = random.nextInt(list.size());
    String[] s = list.get(listAccess);
    return s[random.nextInt(s.length)];
}
```

Then, simply replace the `System.out.println(cuisine[0,1]);` with

```
System.out.println(getRandom(cuisine));
```

For your question why your code doesn't compile, this is because you have to use `.get(<index>)` for a `List`, and `[<index>]` to access an item out of an Array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your import statements will not compile as written.

`import java.util.; //will not compile without class name after '.'
import java.util.*; //will compile: You could also specify a specific class name in place of the *`

As for generating a random restaurant, you can do so by adding the following code to your main method. I've added comments for explanation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String[]> cuisine = new ArrayList<>();

    cuisine.add(italian);
    cuisine.add(japanese);
    cuisine.add(french);
    cuisine.add(american);
    cuisine.add(chinese);
    cuisine.add(spanish);
    cuisine.add(cafe);
    cuisine.add(thai);
    cuisine.add(indian);
    cuisine.add(viatnamese);

    Random randomArrayListIndex = new Random();

    int randomCuisine = randomArrayListIndex
            .nextInt(cuisine.size());

    String[] randomArray = cuisine.get(randomCuisine); // get random array
                                                        // from ArrayList

    Random randomArrayIndex = new Random();

    String randomRestaurant = randomArray[randomArrayIndex // get random element
                                                        // from array
            .nextInt(randomArray.length)];
    System.out.println(randomRestaurant);
}
```

Comment: `(randomArray.length - 1) - 0) + 1` what is the purpose of this?

Comment: Good catch. I wrote it too fast and didn't think through it entirely...I was originally thinking I would need to subtract 1 from the length of the array or the size of the ArrayList since that number won't be a valid index.

Comment: `randomArrayIndex.nextInt(size)`will automatically get the next int from `[0,size-1] or [0,size)` as it is non-inclusive of the parameter. :)

Comment: Yeah I remembered that after you made your initial comment. It pays off to look at the API from time to time :)